# QT Phonon Audio jumping bars

Tags: c++, qt, audio, phonon

Im only here to ask one question. Well im working in an application, but I would like to create that jumping bars, that jumps with the music. I dont know if you understand me, here is an image of what i want to do:


[image: example]



I dont know how to create that bars, so I dont know if you can help me.
Thank you very much.

---

With Phonon, how can I handle the frequencies?

Comment: Easiest graphics in C++ is GDI+ library as i know.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I get the frequency (the wave) of the audio and, what does each bar means?

Comment: Probably first bar is 16-Hz sound and next is 32Hz next 64 128 256 512 1024. Second bar-set: 2048 4096 8192 16k 32k (you know human ear limit is 20kHz)